# Sort Nested Array Abject

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, sorting

I am trying to sort a nested array and running into an issue doing that. I got it working if I specify the index, which won't work...need to loop through all values

**Array**

```
items= [{
    app_type_id: 1,
    apps: [{

          app_id: 3,
          app_type_id: 1,
          app_name: "Test1"

        },
        {
          app_id: 2,
          app_type_id: 1,
          app_name: "Test2"

        },
        {
          app_id: 107,
          app_type_id: 1,
          app_name: "Test3"
        }
      }]
  }]
```

**TS**

```
this.iarray[0].apps.sort((a, b) => a.app_name[0] > b.app_name[1] ? 1 : -1)
```

above will work only for the first two items..in reality the number might be larger (Dynamic)apps number..how can I change it to sort through all apps

Comment: what does this have anything to do with angular?

Comment: and why are you comparing `a.app_name[0] > b.app_name[1]` with different indices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the mistake is that you should compare `app_name` values but you are in fact comparing the first and second characters.

Your code should (supposedly) be:

```
items.apps.sort((a, b) => a.app_name > b.app_name ? 1 : -1)
```